# In Blade Runner, did Pris's death imply that she was in some way mechanical/electrical?

Tags: blade-runner

I am sure people asked this before but I am not finding it online. It seemed to me that when she was shot her reaction is not at all similar to that of a human shot in the abdomen. She went into convulsions which I would imagine could happen with direct brain injury. We see blood although somehow I am remembering sparks in some version (perhaps just from the weapon -- I recall also that when the Joanna Cassady character was shot it also looked like sparks *from* her body). In any case, her reaction to being shot does not seem very human. Perhaps this was to indicate that she was very resilient and would not simply drop dead or moan inertly in pain as a human would.

I want to make the importance of the release of the movie before the Internet clear: There was in those days no place to discuss these kind of issues and I can say that I and other people who saw the first run did think that replicants might be robotic. And that the eyes of replicants are grown separately suggests that they are assembled like a machine, not grown in a vat like a clone might be.

So someone seeing the movie years after it was first released might have a very different view of the meaning of such a scene than would someone seeing it when it was new.

Comment: What do you mean "imply"? Pris is a replicant, and while it's been a while since I watched Blade Runner, I'm certain this is revealed long before her death.

Comment: yes, she was a replicant and so her nature would be like that of the others.

Comment: down-voting because you disagree with the conclusion or inference of the questioner I do not think is valid -- the idea is to exchange views, not simply post something that everyone else will agree with. downvotes should be for questions that are, for example, already answered, etc.

Comment: "the idea is to exchange views" No, it is not. This is not a forum. Please [**follow the tour**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB: i guess my point is, a question that you think the answer is "no" to should not be downvoted. maybe the point is not to exchange views but one should be willing to accept that a question might reflect a different view than your own and yet not need to be downvoted.

Comment: Pris IS in some way mechanical/electrical! That’s a central plot point of the movie! Pris, Roy, Leon, and Zora are all robots that are very convincingly human-like, but they are not humans. Deckard is assigned to hunt them down because these robots are prohibited on Earth. Pris is not human. She’s a robot.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I am pretty sure they are not supposed to be robots or have mechanical components.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: based on the rules for the site, what do you feel a good reason for down-voting a question is? Is it a way of saying, "No" more emphatically or is it to indicate the question is not valid, for example. the answer is obvious or the question does not make sense.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean. Are you saying “replicant” is not a fancy word for “robot”? What do you think replicants are if they aren’t robots?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: if they are biological, grown in artificial wombs as implied in the sequel, then they would be very close to humans in the way they responded to being shot. I don't think Pris reacted like a human would and my question is why?

Comment: Ok I see. Well Pris and the rest are Nexus 6 and I thought the ones in the sequel were something else, beyond nexus 6. You might want to add the part about the sequel to the question. There’s nothing in the first movie to suggest that replicants would react to being shot just like a human does. Only Leon dies somewhat like a human. Zora keeps running after being shot multiple times and goes through several plate glass windows like it’s nothing. Humans can’t do that.

Comment: @releseabe If you hover over the downvote button, it gives several reasons why users might downvote. In the end, users do what they do, and complaining about downvotes is pointless and counterproductive. Write a clear and relevant question and people won't downvote. Your edit should have improved your question, instead you added a bunch of irrelevant noise, e.g. "I want to make the importance of the release of the movie before the Internet clear: There was in those days no place to discuss these kind of issues".

Comment: Comments are not intended for extended discussion.  Particularly the discussion that doesn't directly relate to the content of the question could move to a chat room if people wanted to continue that.

Comment: You might want to clarify that you are well aware that she is a replicant but are looking into the finer difference between organic clones and robots. It is an interesting difference indeed and the film does actually never go into detail what the replicants really are, sometimes implying they're genetically engineered clones but sometimes also equating them to robots (although, the sequel does lean more in the former direction)...

Comment: ...However, an immediate reaction to seeing this question title is exactly the one you got in various comments, namely "well, yeah, that's the point, duh!". And not actually concentrating on that difference in the question, rather than some rambling about the internet and how mysterious this question you didn't actually ask other than in the title actually is, doesn't quite help to bring this point across. (Neither does insulting the commenters.)

Comment: I saw your comment on a totally different question related to this one where you suggested those who had downvoted this one were preteens and that the system should reward interesting and valuable questions. I’m 47 years old and I find this question to be the opposite of useful or interesting. I find one major problem this question has is the word “mechanical”. Normal human beings are mechanical. We are also electrical. Perhaps you meant to ask if replicants are made from metal or other non-living tissue. Pris’ death in no way suggests that and it’s not clear why you would think it might.

Comment: It also doesn’t make sense to me that you would question whether replicants are “robotic” because the opening text literally calls them robots. Perhaps they are robots created using cloning of tissues and genetic engineering and perhaps they have bones and blood in them. That wouldn’t make them not robots. I saw it soon after it was released in the original cut with the “happy” ending, so I’m not subject to your concerns about the lack of internet back then, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this really is that "nobody knows", not for certain. Their composition changed with each telling.
Ridley Scott insists that they were biological, but their behaviour isn't that of a purely biological entity. There's a lot of grey area.

From [Wikipedia - Replicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicant)

> In his novel Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep? (the inspiration for Blade Runner), Philip K. Dick used the term android (or "andy"), but director Ridley Scott wanted a new term that the audience would not have any preconceptions about. As David Peoples was re-writing the screenplay, he consulted his daughter, who was involved in microbiology and biochemistry. She suggested the term "replicating", the biological process of a cell making a copy of itself. From that, either Peoples or Scott—each would later recall it was the other—came up with replicant, and it was inserted into Hampton Fancher's screenplay.

> Although the press kit for the film explicitly defines a replicant as "A genetically engineered creature composed entirely of organic substance", the physical make-up of the replicants themselves is not clear. In the films's preamble, it is noted that replicants are said to be the result of "advanced robot evolution." The preamble also states that replicants were created by genetic engineers. Characters mention that replicants have eyes and brains like humans, and they are seen to bleed when injured. The only way of telling a replicant from a human is to ask a series of questions and analyze emotional responses, suggesting they might be entirely, or almost entirely, organic. The film also shows that at least certain body parts of a replicant are separately engineered and assembled, as shown with Hannibal Chew, a genetic engineer who specifically made replicant eyes. In a deleted scene, J.F. Sebastian was stated to have made replicant hands along with his own personal robotic toys.

> Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep? makes mention of the biological components of the androids, but also alludes to mechanical aspects commonly found in other material relating to robots. It states that the bone marrow can be tested to prove whether it is from a human or replicant.

> In May 2012, Scott confirmed that the replicants were biological in nature, and contrasted them to the androids in the Alien series:
>
> Roy Batty was an evolved... He wasn't an engine. If I cut him open, there wasn't metal, he was grown... and then within twenty years you get the first bill not passed in the Senate where they applied for replication of animals, sheep and goats and cattle and animals and they turned it down, but if you can do that, then you can do human beings. If you go deeper into it and say 'Yeah, but if you are going to grow a human being, does he start that big and I've got to see him through everything?' I don't want to answer the question, because of course he does... Ash in Alien had nothing to do with Roy Batty, because Roy Batty is more humanoid, whereas Ash was more metal.

As regards Pris' reluctance to 'just die'…

> During the creation process of a replicant, their physical and mental capacities are separately ranked on a A to C system and designated for each replicant with the C level representing below normal human ability, B level being equal to a normal human and A being above normal human ability, the latter of which leads to superhuman physicality or genius level intelligence.

Pris was A-class physically…

> Pris Stratton (played by Daryl Hannah) is referred to as a "basic pleasure model" for military personnel (Physical-A, Mental-B, N6FAB21416.)

Also from [Wikipedia - List of *Blade Runner* characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Blade_Runner_characters#Pris_Stratton)

> At an A-Physical Level, she is shown to have superhuman endurance (as in the scene where she grabs a boiling egg with her bare hand without harm) and an affinity for gymnastics.

Comment: They’re obviously at least partly biological. They bleed.

Comment: The Nexus 7 also **breeds**, but the first movie was all about the Nexus 6. The 2nd is about the Nexus 8, where further confusion is added ;)) I always get the impression they weren't quite sure when they made the first one & never expected such minute scrutiny as it eventually attracted.